# How to create a Map[String,String] from Map[String, Any] in Scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, any

New to scala - How to create a `Map[String,String]`  from `Map[String, Any]` 
The values of the `Map[String,Any]` are strings but I don't know how to cast or otherwise coerce the "`Any`" type to a "`String`" type.

Comment: If you know they are strings, why does the compiler think they are Any?

Comment: I have a function that retrieves the param names and values from  case classes. It returns them as Map[String,Any] because the values could be of any type. I'm used to Java where I can just cast to the type I want. I discovered that I can use 'Any.asInstanceOf[String]' to get the same effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you mentioned that all the values in your map are strings, you can simply use `asInstanceOf`. If your assumption is incorrect, you will receive runtime exceptions as demonstrated below:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_55).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val m:Map[String, Any] = Map("foo" -> 5, "bar" -> 7.6, "baz" -> "qux")
m: Map[String,Any] = Map(foo -> 5, bar -> 7.6, baz -> qux)

scala> val m2: Map[String, Any] = Map("foo" -> "5", "bar" -> "7.6", "baz" -> "qux")
m2: Map[String,Any] = Map(foo -> 5, bar -> 7.6, baz -> qux)

scala> m2.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]
res0: Map[String,String] = Map(foo -> 5, bar -> 7.6, baz -> qux)
```

This is perfect when all values are actually of type `String`.

```
scala> res0("foo")
res5: String = 5
```

Watch out for your wrong assumption:

```
scala> m.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]
res2: Map[String,String] = Map(foo -> 5, bar -> 7.6, baz -> qux)

scala> res2("foo")
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at .<init>(<console>:10)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$14.apply(IMain.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:43)
    at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 3):

Having a `Map[String, Any]` in the first place is a sign something has probably gone off the rails, although without any code to look at, I can't really help you there. Typically, when you start to see `Any`s and other super-generic types inferred, it's Scala's type system telling you that the code you've written does not mean what you think it means.

If you *really* want to do this, you can do:

```
scala> val m = Map("foo" -> 5, "bar" -> 7.6, "baz" -> "qux")
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(foo -> 5, bar -> 7.6, baz -> qux)

scala> m.mapValues(_.toString)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(foo -> 5, bar -> 7.6, baz -> qux)
```

Comment: it doesn't necessarily mean code has gone off the rails, it can just mean that  someone had to use a java library in their scala code (like a ServletRequest parameter map)

Comment: @AndrewNorman Hence "probably" :) I agree there are legitimate reasons to have an `Any`, but I stick with the assessment that it's probably indicative of a logical error, and the least-upper bound being inferred of some set of unrelated types.

Answer (score 2):

As the others have already mentioned, the fact that have an `Any` in the first place, is a sign that something somewhere has gone wrong. The correct solution would be to figure out what went wrong where and fix it.

However, if you *really* want to cast all the values to `String`s (which is circumventing the type system, and thus something you *shouldn't* do), here's how you do it:

```
val anyMap: Map[String, Any] = Map("foo" -> "bar", "baz" -> "qux")

val stringMap = anyMap.mapValues(_.asInstanceOf[String])
// => stringMap: Map[String, String] = Map(foo -> bar, baz -> qux)
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of `Map[String,Any]` as inferred by the compiler includes

```
val a = Map( "s" -> 1, "t" -> "w" )
a: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(s -> 1, t -> w)
```

where the *least* common type for `Int` and `String` is `Any`.

Apply `toString` to each value in the map.